# How to draw a free body diagram of a cylinder under torsion?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, dynamics, springs

What is the correct way to draw a free body diagram (FBD) for the following cylinder? Assume the cylinder and disc have been twisted to an angular deflection of $\theta$. Further assume that we are drawing the FBD immediately after releasing the disc, so static equilibrium *does not* hold.

[image]

I know there is a restorative force that grows as $\theta$ gets larger. But how should I write it? Do I need to talk about the shear stress? Or can I simply write a restorative force $F_t$ tangent to the surface of the disc at the bottom?

For example, would this be a correct FBD?

[image]

Would it be correct to also write the moment or torque that the force at the surface creates? Or is this redundant and would imply, according to the diagram, double the moment acting on the disc?

[image]

Comment: The free-body diagram shall consist of all forces acting on it and the resulting reactions. For your case, you have the applied torque on the disc and the twist on the shaft support. IMO, Ft is an imaginary force, which does not need to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is redundant. The FBD usually comes with a section or call out to indicate where is it at.

If you mean to drive the harmonic vibration of this system you can idealize it to a moment of inertia, m, and rotational stiffness, k.

$$k= \frac{T}{\theta }= \frac{GJ}{L}$$

and assuming a small damping.

$$\omega_{n}= \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all the problem described --i.e. twisting then releasing -- seem like a dynamics problem (more  than a statics one).

Additionally, (and this will become more relevant below) is that the problem as it is described is a *torsional spring*.

There are a few subtle points.

1. it is not described how the beam ends up in the $\theta$ angular displacement. Is it a force like the one below?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk2f9.png]

if that is the case then you'd be expected to have some lateral displacement, so I suspect it is moment that is applied.

This means that upon release the FBD of the beam has only a reaction force from the support.

2. Upon release the entire beam is still "feeling" reaction force, and is starting to untwist. This is very much  the same way that when you extend a spring and then you let it go, the reaction force is proportional to the position. (Actually the problem as it is described is a torsional spring.)

So the force will be proportional to the

3. Usually, in the beam as twisting and the disk (due to its massively greater second moment of area) as a rigid component. If you can further assume that the beam is massless then the problem approximates very well that of the spring and mass.
4. Finally, in this type of dynamics problems it is best to draw two types of diagrams. The FBD which sums up the forces, and the *kinetic diagram* with all the inertial forces. E.g. for a sliding block the FBD and kinetic diagram are shown below.

[image]

Essentially they reflect the two sides of the equation $\sum F = m\cdot a$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. I agree that this is a dynamics problem, and let's say that the deflection $\theta$ came about from a moment and not a force like $F_t$. In my drawing, $F_t$ is meant to be the torsional reaction force. So is my FBD (without the moment) correct?